# Is there a better way of writing native SQL query with EntityManager Java Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager

My current code look like this. I am not using any ORM framework like Hibernate. I need to use this raw SQL query.

```java
public List<String> getEndcodedKeyByLenderId(String lenderId) {
    Query q = (Query) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT clients.encoded_key FROM `users`\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN clients on clients.`user_id` = users.id AND (clients.currency = 'EUR')\n" +
            "WHERE `users`.`user_type` = 'Lender' AND `users`.`id` = :user_id LIMIT 1;");
    q.setParameter("user_id", lenderId);
    List<String> results = q.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

I don't like so many " and \n  and + symbol.

Is there better way to approach for same result?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm tracking with you as to why you're using `EntityManager` (a JPA API) if you are not using an ORM framework, but you could put the query into a Text Block (multiline String) since Java 15.

Comment: Thanks @BriceRoncace, can you show me some example?

Comment: See documentation regarding [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html#introduction)

Comment: (1) Define 'better' (2) You don't *need* the `\n` symbols, a space would do just as well

Answer (score 1):

[Java Text Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html) to the rescue!  (aka multiline Strings.) This has been a feature in Java since Java 15.

Formatting SQL in Java code is the primary use case in our environment.  Here's an example using your query:

```
 String query = """
  SELECT clients.encoded_key FROM users
  LEFT JOIN clients on clients.user_id = users.id AND (clients.currency = 'EUR')
  WHERE users.user_type = 'Lender' AND users.id = :user_id LIMIT 1
  """;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's a lot nicer.